# Joint image and data display in a gridview bound to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good evening

I am inserting book items into a table of an access database on a web service from my web site and this table I add to a dataset(using a method in the web service) which I return to the website and bind to a gridview control to display the items. So far so good.

My problem is that I would ideally want to display images that should also be inserted along with the other detail such as book title and author. It is however very tricky to add images to a access database and I am therefore asking for advice(pointer) as to how display the images in my gridview along with the book items.

Should I add the images to the App_dat folder which is what I am thinking but how to add the pictures so that they are displayed together with the correct book items?.

Answer (score 0):

You could either store the path to the image in the table and save the image on disk (that way the image is associated with the record), or you could use store the image in the table. I've not tried storing images in Access, but I know it's possible.

If it's an option (it may not be but worth mentioning), consider switching to a more easy to use (opinion of course) file based database like [SQL CE](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Store the URL of the image as one of the fields in the database. Then you can add a field to your grid view that displays the image. A brief tutorial is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx).